# moment.js same time everywhere

Tags: javascript, time, dst, momentjs

I was writing a chrome extension this morning and the everything seems fine.

However by night time I had noticed that the time being displayed is wrong.
At first I thought it was a code problem but after going onto their site it seems like every single places the time were all displaying my local time.

Is anyone experiencing this same problem? 
Or should I consider changing the library all together...

I've recorded a video here
http://youtu.be/g6n6nXJt_uU

`function setClock()
    {
        now = moment.tz(moment.tz().format("MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm"),
    "EST").format("MM/DD/YYYY hh:mma"); 
    document.getElementById("time").innerHTML=now + " NYC";
    }
    console.log(moment.tz("EST")._d);
    console.log(moment()._d);
    setClock();
    setInterval(setClock,1000);`

[CodeOutputHere](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6aOyzbX7M0Lek01NFZqX21YSDA/edit?usp=drivesdk)

Comment: Please read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). In particular here you could provide in the text the time at which you loaded the page, what time the page was displaying, and if you and the server were in different time zones.

Comment: 1. 5 minutes before I posted this 2. My local time which is the same as the video->>2:58AM 3. my time is UTC+8:00 in Taiwan @JasonAller

Comment: Just posted a picture for the code output, it keeps showing my local time when in fact I need the time for NYC. @JasonAller

Comment: Why are you wrapping a call to `moment.tz()` inside another call to the same function when you set now? In particular it looks like the inner instance has `"EST"` and the outer one doesn't.

Comment: I can confirm though that when I go to http://momentjs.com/timezone/, if I mouse over any of the dots on the map, they all show my local time (EST) when I assume they're supposed to show the time in that place. I don't know what the issue is but I see it here too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding your code:

- You should not use time zone abbreviations like `EST` for this purpose, since [time zone abbreviations are often ambiguous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone_abbreviations).  If you're looking to set US Eastern Time, then you should be using [the IANA time zone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database) identifier of `America/New_York`.

  `EST` only exists in the tzdb for backwards compatibility purposes.  Arguably, it should be left out of the moment-timezone data.
- Calling `moment.tz()` without any argument is not recommended.  You should just call `moment()`.
- Your code appears to be formatting a moment, then parsing it into another moment, then formatting it out again.  There's no reason to jump through so many hoops.
- You should not use the `_d` property.  That is meant to be internal to moment.js.  (It should probably be hidden by closure, but it's not).   Instead, use `.format()` or one of the other public functions.

Ultimately, I think you are simply after:

```
var now = moment().tz('America/New_York').format("MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm");
```

I highly suggest you re-read the [moment-timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/) and [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/) documentation.

Regarding the moment-timezone web site with the map - you're correct that there's currently a bug with the demonstration web site.  It is not a bug with the library itself.  I'll investigate and report that to the moment team.

Comment: 1. I actually used that in the first place, decided to change it after for some reason the output become the way it was. 2. I actually forgot to change it back because I was using moment() and decided to try and find an alternative LOL 3. First time using this library and was trying to get function working. I just stumbled upon this library today and wanted to get the function up first so I stumbled upon an example using moment.tz(DATE, TIMEZONE).format(FORMAT) so I just parsed moment() into it. I agree I should spend some time reading more thoroughly -----5.This fixed the problem, Thank you!!